# Gradle: Multi-project build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

So I have a project structure as follows

```
root
|-- module-1
|-- module-2
.
.
|-- module-n
```

The final artifact we are looking at is the combined jar of all sources from all the modules. I am not sure whether this is the right way.
Here is my build-script :

```
   plugins {
        id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "1.2.3"
    }

    group = 'com.root'
    version = System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER') ?:'1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    configurations { providedCompile }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    def sparkVersion = '2.0.0'
    def scalaMajorVersion = '2.11'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['module1/src/main/java', 'module2/src/main/java']
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name:'scala-compiler', version:'2.11.8'
        compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '0.9.0.0'
        compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-streaming-kafka_$scalaMajorVersion", version: '1.6.2'
        compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-streaming_$scalaMajorVersion", version: "$sparkVersion"
        compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-catalyst_$scalaMajorVersion", version: "$sparkVersion"
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
        compile group: 'org.apache.zookeeper', name: 'zookeeper', version: '3.4.9'
        providedCompile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-core_$scalaMajorVersion", version: "$sparkVersion"
        providedCompile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-sql_$scalaMajorVersion", version: "$sparkVersion"
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    }

    build.dependsOn(shadowJar);

    shadowJar {
        zip64 true
    }

    sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
    sourceSets.test.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
    sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.providedCompile

    artifacts {
        archives file: shadowJar.archivePath, builtBy: shadowJar
    }
```

So we are just appending sourceSets when a new module is added.

I just wanted to confirm whether this is the right way to build a multi-module project, if not what is the right way? and how to account for inter module dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be duplicating logic since each module compiles `.java` to `.class` but then you do it again when aggregating. If it were me, I'd have the following modules

```
root
|-- module-1
|-- module-2
.
.
|-- module-n
+-- uber
```

And in the `uber` module I'd use [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to aggregate the compiled `.class` files. Your `uber/build.gradle` might look like

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    runtime project(':module-1')
    runtime project(':module-2')
    runtime project(':module-N')
}

shadowJar {
   baseName = 'foo'
   classifier = 'bar'
   version = project.version
}
```

Comment: so every module will have its own gradle file? if yes how will it look?

Comment: Unlike maven, gradle doesn't dictate this. You can have all modules in a single file, each module in a separate file or a combination of both. I suggest you read the gradle documentation on multi module builds